# How to use the DeserializerBuilder?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

When trying to use YamlDotNet, I run into this warning:

> Deserializer.Deserializer(IObjectFactory, INamingConvention, bool,
>   YamlAttributeOverrides) is obsolete: 'Please use DeserializerBuilder
>   to customize the Deserializer. This constructor will be removed in
>   future releases.'

So I go to the official project homepage:

And click the 'Deserializing an object graph' example, which leads me here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/HD2JXM

And, surprisingly, this too is using the obsolete function.

I *fixed* it by doing this:

```
DeserializerBuilder groupIDsDB = new DeserializerBuilder();
groupIDsDB.WithNamingConvention(new CamelCaseNamingConvention());
Deserializer groupIDsDeserializer = groupIDsDB.Build();
```

Instead of my earlier:

```
Deserializer groupIDsDeserializer = new Deserializer(namingConvention: new CamelCaseNamingConvention());
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way of using the `DeserializerBuilder`. The examples have not all been updated and some still use the old constructor.

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote you and super late reply, but marked as answer. Thanks! <3